# Get next element with class which is not sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings, nextsibling

I want to traverse through `page`s and toggle `active` class through them. How should I do this **without using `set` class**?

**HTML**

```
<div class="page active"></div>
<div class="set">
    <div class="page"></div>
    <div class="page"></div>
</div>
<div class="page"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.active').toggleClass('active').toggle().nextAll('.page').toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: Why don'y you do `$('.page').toggleClass('active')` it will toggle everything to the opposite way.

Comment: why not use `.parent()` or `.closest()` then do `find('.active')`

Comment: You are using ``toggleClass()`` and ``toggle()`` i think there is a better way, where you can omit one of the two.

Comment: @Trix you want to exclude one page right? why not use `:not('.page .active')`

Comment: You can use current `.page.active` index, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/wdw4t0he/

Comment: @A.Wolff I want to know if there is any clear jQuery way to select the next element in DOM having a `page` class

Comment: No there isn't any simpler solution AFAIK and there is nothing wrong with using index, anyway

Comment: @A.Wolff Please submit your solution, so I can accept it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by "traverse" you mean you want to toggle the `.page` divs one by one in a certain order.
If that is the case, write an algorithm that traverses a tree: given a root, toggle if it is a `.page`, and recursively deal with each of its children

```
function traverse(root){
  if(!root) return;
  if(root.hasClass('page')) root.toggle('active');
  root.children().forEach(function(child){
    traverse(child);
  });

  //lets say you want to bind to click event on every div
  $('div').click(function(){
    traverse($(this));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/151/)**

You could achieve that using indexes to get the next element in the DOM using the index of active one `+1` then active it, I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
var getActiveIndex = function(){
    var active_index;
    $('.page').each(function(i){
        if ( $(this).hasClass('active') )
            active_index = i;
    })
    return active_index;
}

$('body').on('click', '.next', function(){
    var active_page_index = getActiveIndex(); //Get active page index
    var new_index = active_page_index+1; //Set the next page index
    var next_page = $('.page:eq('+new_index+')'); //Get the next page

    $('.page').removeClass('active');

    if(next_page.length)
      next_page.addClass('active');
    else
      $('.page:first').addClass('active');
})
```

I hope this helps.

```js
var getActiveIndex = function(){
  var active_index;
  $('.page').each(function(i){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') )
      active_index = i;
  })
  return active_index;
}

$('body').on('click', '.next', function(){
  var active_page_index=getActiveIndex();
  var new_index = active_page_index+1;
  var next_page = $('.page:eq('+new_index+')');

  $('.page').removeClass('active');

  if(next_page.length)
    next_page.addClass('active');
  else
    $('.page:first').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red; 
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page active">page</div>
<div class="set">
  <div class="page">- Set page</div>
  <div class="page">- Set page</div>
</div>
<div class="page">page</div>
<div class="page">page</div>
<div class="page">page</div>
<div class="set">
  <div class="page">- Set page</div>
  <div class="page">- Set page</div>
</div>
<div class="page">page</div>
<br>
<button class='next'>Active the next page</button>
```

Comment: Tnx for ur time and answer, but please not as I stated clearly, I dont want to jump over `page`s within `set`s. I want to traverse over ALL `page`s, whether it is in or out of a `set`.

Comment: @Trix is that not what you looking for ?

Comment: using index has been offered by @A. Wolff in comments, but I think this is like a work around and there should be other clear way to do this.

Comment: It's just a flash on the comment and works by click on the active link (I can't find that in your OP) what make it a little bit easy.. and it's may a workaround because jquery not offer a function that could do the trick smoothly yet, so IMO it's just the possible way to to achieve your desired result.. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't have a direct way to find the next non sibling element, but we can handle that situation in many ways using jquery functions. I just tried on way to achieve your goal, check out [this working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjqg4wun/1/) and let me know if you need any clarity, added some inline comments also for your understanding.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page active">div 1</div>
<div class="page">div 2</div>
<div class="set">
    <div class="page">set 1 - div 1</div>
    <div class="page">set 1 - div 2</div>
    <div class="page">set 1 - div 3</div>
</div>
<div class="page">div 5</div>
<div class="set">
    <div class="page">set 2 - div 1</div>
    <div class="page">set 2 - div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="page">div 6</div>
<button class="next-btn">Next</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
  color: red;
}
.next-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var elem = $(".page.active").toggleClass('active'); // current active element
    var nextElem = elem.next(); // next element

    // go above one level and get next element
    // if no next element exists, means end of the child level
    if (!nextElem.length) {
        nextElem = elem.parent().next();
    }

    // if next element has some PAGE children then update the first child element 
    if (nextElem.children('.page').length > 0 ) {
        nextElem.children('.page:first-child').toggleClass('active');
    } else if (nextElem.hasClass('page')) {
        nextElem.toggleClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

This approach handles the scenario with one child level, you can extend this to multiple levels also with recursive functions, I think this helps you to handle your scenario accordingly.